# Not able to access managed user content

Tags: box-api, box

I am getting error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Cannot obtain token based on the enterprise configuration”}
```

for my app while trying to take access token using JWT.

Any idea how I can access content of manage users which is not app user?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the JWT Authentication is specific to accounts that are designated as App Users. Since they do not have their own login, and they are purely managed through an application, the JWT Auth method was implemented to allow for programmatic access.

JWT is not meant as a replacement for the standard three-legged OAuth 2.0 approach for retrieving tokens for managed users, and as such, you should utilize the flow which is described in some more detail here:
https://box-content.readme.io/docs/oauth-20

The OAuth tokens are scoped based on who logs in through the application. If a managed user logs in, the access token received will have access to the content that the user has within the Box Web App. If an enterprise admin goes through that process, the token that is generated will reflect the admin permissions, being able to manage the content of users within the enterprise by utilizing the [As-User Header](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#as-user-1).